# How to enable debug logging for Ballerina test cases?

Tags: testing, logging, ballerina

I need to enable debug-level logging for my Ballerina test cases. What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable debug logging for Ballerina test cases:

1. Create a `Config.toml` file in your test directory.
2. Add this to `Config.toml`:

   ```ini
   [ballerina.log]
   level = "DEBUG"
   ```
3. Run your tests, and debug-level logs will be displayed. Logging can be further customized as needed using the official documentation: [logging configuration](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/logging-configuration/).